# Como imprimir os 12 primeiros termos da sequencia de Fibonacci de forma inversa em Pascal?

Tags: pascal, fibonnaci

Como imprimir os dos primeiros 12 termos da sequência de Fibonacci de forma inversa em Pascal? Ao invés de ser do 1 ao 12,do 12 para o 1

```
program Exercicio_31;

var V:array[3..12]of integer;I,termo1,termo2,novoTermo:integer;

begin


     writeln('Serie de Fibonacci');
     writeln('==================');
     termo1 := 1;
     termo2 := 1;
     writeln(' 1o. termo = ', termo1);
     writeln(' 2o. termo = ', termo2);
     for I:=12 downto 3 do 
     begin
        novoTermo := termo1 + termo2; { o novo termo e a soma dos dois termos anteriores }
        writeln(I:2, 'o. termo = ', novoTermo);
        termo1 := termo2;   {o segundo termo e o primeiro termo no proximo passo }
        termo2:=novoTermo; { o novo termo e o segundo termo no proximo passo }
     end;
     writeln('==================');
     writeln;
     write('Pressione [algo] para prosseguir.');
     readkey;
end.
```

Comment: Aparentemente trata-se de uma questão de faculdade.

Comment: Sim,é de faculdade.

Comment: Antes de fazer a pergunta diretamente, esponha como tentou chegar a solução e os problemas que encontrou na implementação. Não apresente a questão diretamente sem demonstrar nenhum esforço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A maneira mais simples é começar a iteração já com o valor do 12o número e do 11o número e ir subtraindo-os até chegar nos valores iniciais da sequência:

```
program Exercicio_31;

var V:array[3..12]of integer;
I,termo1,termo2,novoTermo:integer;

begin


     writeln('Serie de Fibonacci');
     writeln('==================');
     termo1 := 144;
     termo2 := 89;
     writeln('12o. termo = ', termo1);
     writeln('11o. termo = ', termo2);
     for I:= 10 downto 1 do 
     begin
        novoTermo := termo1 - termo2; { o novo termo e a soma dos dois termos anteriores }
        writeln(I, 'o. termo = ', novoTermo);
        termo1 := termo2;   {o segundo termo e o primeiro termo no proximo passo }
        termo2 := novoTermo; { o novo termo e o segundo termo no proximo passo }
     end;
     writeln('==================');
     writeln;
     write('Pressione [algo] para prosseguir.');
end.
```

Saída

> Serie de Fibonacci
>
> ==================
>   12o. termo = 144
>   11o. termo = 89
>   10o. termo = 55
>   9o. termo = 34
>   8o. termo = 21
>   7o. termo = 13
>   6o. termo = 8
>   5o. termo = 5
>   4o. termo = 3
>   3o. termo = 2
>   2o. termo = 1
>   1o. termo = 1
>
> ==================

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado pela ajuda.